# How do I use find to search for symlink names under OS X?

Tags: macos, find, symlink

I'm familiar with the `-lname` option to find, but it isn't working as I would expect it to.  Specifically, it doesn't seem to match anything, unless I am in the same directory as the symlink.  This is useless as I have a quite nested directory structure I'm trying to search in and find's recursiveness is what I need.

Here is a simplified example of the problem I am seeing.  I have a directory that has 7 subdirectories:

```
$ ls
01  02  03  04  05  06  07
```

Each directory has 100 symlinks except for 07, which has around 20.  But when I run find, I get nothing.

```
$ find . -lname "*"
$
```

However, if I cd into the 07 directory, suddenly find works:

```
$ cd 07
$ find . -lname "*"
./DSC_4599.JPG
./DSC_4601.JPG
./DSC_4602.JPG
./DSC_4603.JPG
./DSC_4604.JPG
./DSC_4605.JPG
./DSC_4612.JPG
./DSC_4613.JPG
./DSC_4614.JPG
./DSC_4615.JPG
./DSC_4616.JPG
./DSC_4617.JPG
./DSC_4618.JPG
./DSC_4619.JPG
./DSC_4620.JPG
./DSC_4621.JPG
./DSC_4622.JPG
./DSC_4623.JPG
./DSC_4624.JPG
./DSC_4625.JPG
./DSC_4626.JPG
./DSC_4627.JPG
$
```

The listing of this directories shows along these lines:

```
$ ls -l
total 176
lrwxr-xr-x  1 michael  staff  52 Jul  1 21:15 DSC_4599.JPG -> ../../../md5/fb/fb70d93d1051896d180d1cbeb19d2d00.JPG
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `find` to follow the symlink. `find -L`, at least on FreeBSD which is pretty close to osx.

```
angst(~/test2) > ll -l
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 antiduh  antiduh     8B Jul  3 20:09 binlink@ -> /usr/bin
-rw-r--r--  1 antiduh  antiduh     0B Jul  3 20:09 sekrits
angst(~/test2) > find .
.
./sekrits
./binlink
angst(~/test2) > find -L .
.
./sekrits
./binlink
./binlink/bc
./binlink/addr2line
```

Comment: Ah thanks... I read another answer which seemed to suggest I should NOT use -L, but that works!